# Install latest version of tree command

Tags: apt, package-management, tree

I installed the tree command today on Ubuntu 18.04 using:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install tree
```

The version that was installed is:

```
$ tree --version
tree v1.7.0 (c) 1996 - 2014
```

But I see from [here](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) the latest version is 1.8.0

How can I install the latest version of tree?
More generally, how can I ensure the latest versions of programs get installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the two methods to install tree 1.8.0:

1. **Using Snap:**

   Tree is available as a snap package too. You can install it using

   ```
   snap install tree
   ```

   Verify version:

   ```
   tree --version
   ```
2. **Installing deb package**:

   Tree 1.8.0 is packed in Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo). Tree 1.8.0 depends on lib6 (>=2.17). In 18.04 lib6 v2.27 is available. You can download the deb package from Ubuntu pool and install that using dpkg.

   - Download deb package:

     ```
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tree/tree_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
     ```
   - Install using dpkg:

     ```
     sudo dpkg -i tree_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
     ```
   - Install any left dependency:

     ```
     sudo apt install -f
     ```
   - Verify version:

     ```
     tree --version
     ```

     You must get an output like:

     ```
     tree v1.8.0 (c) 1996 - 2018 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Florian Sesser, Kyosuke Tokoro
     ```

#### Further Reading:

- [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/816190)

Answer (score 1):

Download the source package.

decompress the source package.
Change directory into the tree-1.8.0 directory
open a terminal, and type `make`

from the INSTALL File in tree-1.8.0 source:

> Installation instructions:
>
> 1. Edit the Makefile for your OS.  Comment out the Linux options and un-comment    the options for your OS.
> 2. Type: make
> 3. Type: make install
> 4. Enjoy colorful directory trees.

you may find it necessary to run `sudo make install` if you see "permission denied", do that.  I also looked at the MakeFile, you shouldnt have to change anything, just go to step 2, and give the `make` command. if you get errors, update your post.